# Android: Right approach in scheduling a new alarm on upgrade

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an application already in the Play Store. Now, I am going to release an upgrade as part of which a new alarm has to be scheduled. A little context into the alarm:

- When a user installs an app and logs in, this alarm gets scheduled for periodic background sync.

However how will I start this alarm for users who have already installed my app and are logged in? Alarm will eventually get started on next reboot but I would like to understand what is the right approach when trying to start an alarm immediately after an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a broadcast receiver and catch the `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` action to get this done.

example code can be found at http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/android/internal/content/PackageMonitor.java.shtml